# Error al mostrar Banner de Admob en Android Studio

Tags: android, admob

Estoy tratando de colocar un Banner a mi juego, pero cuando lo ejecuto, se muestra el Banner y no juegos, cuando modifico el código, se muestra el juego y no el Banner, este es mi código del "MainAvtivity.java":

NOTA: Busque en internet algunas soluciones y me dicen que debo modificar la variable "setContentView(view);" que muestra el juego y la variable "setContentView(layout);" que muestra el Banner.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;
    MainView view;
    public static final String WIDTH = "width";
    public static final String HEIGHT = "height";
    public static final String SCORE = "score";
    public static final String HIGH_SCORE = "high score temp";
    public static final String UNDO_SCORE = "undo score";
    public static final String CAN_UNDO = "can undo";
    public static final String UNDO_GRID = "undo";
    public static final String GAME_STATE = "game state";
    public static final String UNDO_GAME_STATE = "undo game state";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        view = new MainView(getBaseContext());

        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        view.hasSaveState = settings.getBoolean("save_state", false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean("hasState")) {
                load();
            }
        }
        setContentView(view);

        //Add this in OnCreate of Activity to initialize the ad
        MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");

        //Add this wherever your code needs to add the ad

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

//Additionally to adjust the position to Bottom
        layout.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

// Create a banner ad
        AdView mAdView = new AdView(this);
        mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        mAdView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");

// Create an ad request.
        AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();

// Optionally populate the ad request builder.
        adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);

// Add the AdView to the view hierarchy.
        layout.addView(mAdView);

// Start loading the ad.
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());

        setContentView(layout);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        // Prepare the Interstitial Ad
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
// Insert the Ad Unit ID
        interstitial.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.admob_interstitial_id));

        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
// Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener
        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
// Call displayInterstitial() function
                displayInterstitial();
            }
        });

    }

    public void displayInterstitial() {
    // If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }
    }

    ...
```

Gracias y espero pronta solución.

Answer (score -1):

En realidad es un comportamiento esperado, si revisas la documentación encontraras la razón:

> [setContentView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(android.view.View)) Establece el contenido de la actividad en una
>   vista explícita. Esta vista se coloca directamente en la jerarquía de
>   vista de la actividad. Puede ser una jerarquía de vistas complejas. Al
>   llamar a este método, se ignoran los parámetros de diseño de la vista
>   especificada. Tanto el ancho como el alto de la vista se establecen de
>   forma predeterminada en MATCH_PARENT.

En realidad estas cargando tu layout principal y posteriormente todo el anuncio en tu Activity, por esa razón únicamente ves el anuncio.

```
setContentView(view);
...
...
setContentView(layout);
```

Como solucion te sugiero no usar `setContentView(layout);`, que esta agregando el anuncio, solo agrega el layout a tu vista principal que es `MainView`,

Comment: Hola, me da error: Cannot resolve method 'addView(Android.widget.LinearLayout, int)'

Comment: era un ejemplo, elimina  setContentView(layout); y prueba, comenta resultados.

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar

Comment: asegura que el layout  que tiene el anuncio se agregue a la vista principal, dices que sigue sin funcionar pero no debe desaparecer el juego si es que no muestra el anuncio

Comment: Si entiendo, si yo invierto las posiciones de "setContentView(layout);" y "setContentView(view);" puedo hacer que se muestren el anuncio o el juego (Solo uno de los dos), eso lo tengo bien en claro, pero lo que quiero es que se muestre el juego con el banner en la parte inferior.